# Discrete Mathematics Sets. $∀x∀y(xy ∈ nN) \Rightarrow (x ∈ nN ∨ y ∈ nN)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

3. Let $N = \{0,1,2,3,...\}$ be the set of natural numbers. For a number $n$ let $nN$ denote the set of all multiples of $n$, i.e. $nN = \{nx : x \in N\}$. For each integer $n$ consider the proposition $p(n)$ given by

$∀x∀y(xy \in nN) \Rightarrow (x \in nN ∨ y \in nN)$.

I'm so confused over this question....somebody explain please! I kind of get the first one. The answer to that is (LHS)^¬(RHS) right?

(i) Write down the negation of $p(n)$ without using the implication sign $\Rightarrow$ .

(ii) For which values of $n$, where $2 ≤ n ≤ 7$, is $p(n)$ true? Justify your answer.

(iii) More generally, for which values of $n \in N$ do you think $p(n)$ is true? You do not need to justify your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> $\forall x\;\forall y:(xy \in n\mathbb N) \implies (x \in n\mathbb N \lor y \in n\mathbb N).$
>
> I'm so confused over this question....somebody explain please! I kind of get the first one. The answer to that is $\mathsf {LHS}\land \neg \mathsf{RHS}$ right?

Basically.  $\neg(A\to B) \equiv (A\land\neg B)$

Don't forget to also negate the RHS using DeMorgan's Laws.

> (ii) For which values of $n$, where $2 ≤ n ≤ 7$, is $p(n)$ true? Justify your answer.
>
> (iii) More generally, for which values of $n \in \mathbb N$ do you think $p(n)$ is true? You do not need to justify your answer.

The implication basically states: that if the product of two non-negative integers is a multiple of $n$, then it always follows that at least one them is a multiple of $n$.

So think: For which $n$ is this true, and for which is it not?

Comment: I can't think of an example where it isn't true for n...

Comment: If the negation of p(n) is where the statement isn't true, then does (A∧¬B) translate to "not true when x is in the set AND y is not". This seems to mean _at least one_ of them will be part of the set

Comment: @hchenn Try: $\,2\times 3 \in 6\mathbb N \!\implies\! 2\in 6\mathbb N \lor 3\in 6\mathbb N$

Comment: @hchenn $A$ is the LHS of the implication: $(xy \in n\mathbb N)$ and $B$ is the RHS: $(x \in n\mathbb N \lor y \in n\mathbb N)$

Comment: Ahhh. So 2&3 are examples that work and make p(n) true. It seems that p(n) is true for all values between and including 2&7.

Comment: Is this a correct example to prove p(n) is true for n=7?  X=14,y=2. N=7. Then (14x2)=7(4). Since x(14) is a multiple of 7, then we have that "at least one of them is a multiple if n"

Answer (score 0):

2 or 3 aren't multiples of 6, so its only true for n=6 if x=6 and y=1, that way x is a multple of n

Comment: You have the germ of a good example here, but you've not explained it well.  The Question asks about a proposition $p(n)$ formulated for natural numbers $n\in \mathbb{N}$.  Your example shows that $p(6)$ is false, since $2*3 \in 6\mathbb{N}$ but neither $2\in \mathbb{N}$ nor $3\in \mathbb{N}$.  But the "one-line" answer you gave doesn't point this out very well.  Feel free to edit your answer and improve it!

Comment: So, then, if in a weird universe, 6 was a prime number. p(n) would be true for n=6?
I guess I'm asking p(n) is true for prime numbers?